# RDBMS subscribe to MQTT server Topic and save data

Tags: mqtt

The goal is to store published measurements to an RDBMS.   Mosquitto has been tested on a [Libre Potato](https://libre.computer/products/aml-s905x-cc/) outfitted with Ubuntu.

I have used mySQL for measurements in the past, however, now I would like a database to subscribe to a topic and process \ save the topic messages.  Is there a simple add-on for mySQL that allows sub to MQTT  or another RDBMS that has the ability to subscribe to MQTT?  I am trying to avoid reinventing the wheel.

If not and I have to code subscribe and upload to database, please consider posting a link to a good example.  Thank you

Comment: No, you would have to write your own code to subscribe to relevant mqtt topics and store them in the desired mysql table(s)